# Update order status from processing to completed in WooCommerce automatically on every Monday

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron, orders

I need to update the order status of all 'processing' orders after a specific period of time in WooCommerce. 
I aimed to do this via cron job. So I added this hook in WP Control, with a weekly schedule: woocommerce_complete_processing_order_weekly

Here is what I added in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_complete_processing_order_weekly', 'custom_woocommerce_complete_order', 10, 0 );

function custom_woocommerce_complete_order ( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```

Could you help me out with this?

Comment: Do you want to update all the processing status to completed after one week?

Comment: Hi - yes that would do. But the best case would be if it updates the status one week after payment. But it's also okay if all the orders are changed to completed on Mondays for example...

Comment: Change all the orders means ( any status to completed ) ?

Comment: No, only the orders with status 'processing'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'update_order_status_on_monday' );

function update_order_status_on_monday() {

    if ( date( 'D', strtotime( 'now' ) ) === 'Mon' && !get_transient( '_updated_order_status_on_monday' ) ) {

        $processing_orders   = wc_get_orders( $args              = array(
            'numberposts'    => -1,
            'post_status'    => 'wc-processing',
        ) );

        if ( !empty( $processing_orders ) ) {
            foreach ( $processing_orders as $order )
                $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }
        set_transient( '_updated_order_status_on_monday', true );
    } elseif ( date( 'D', strtotime( 'now' ) ) !== 'Mon' ) {
        delete_transient( '_updated_order_status_on_monday' );
    }
 }
```

Add this code into your active theme functions.php

Comment: thankts. Thats great. But is it also possible to set the time? So it only sets the status once on monday? For example monday 4am?

Comment: @ThomasDanninger - it will run on Monday and all the processing orders will be changed to complete. so that check may not be needed

Comment: okay, but if the order is created on monday, will the status be updated instantly?

Comment: Updated the answer